# Cannot resolve R in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, mobile-application

I tried to clean,rebuild,sync gradle files...
This is my gradle file

> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> android {
>       compileSdkVersion 21
>       buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
>
> ```
> defaultConfig {
>     applicationId "com.example.user.myapplication"
>     minSdkVersion 14
>     targetSdkVersion 21
>     versionCode 1
>     versionName "1.0"
> }
> buildTypes {
>     release {
>         minifyEnabled false
>         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>     }
> } }
> ```
>
> dependencies {
>       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1' }

This also gives error

> 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add above your dependencies

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
}
```

and also you need to add these dependencies.

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.1'
```

and you are done.